# is there a way to select one target when you have more than one calabash target in an iOS project

Tags: cucumber, calabash-ios

i have 2 target setup for calabash in my iOS project. i want to know how i can select one target and run cucumber for that target from the console. when i run, cucumber only runs on the app that was most recently built.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your schemas?  What are you setting for each one?

Comment: i meant the target. I had one for development and one for production with access to the production backend.

Comment: As in the target app?  What are you setting in your schemas and how are you setting them?

Comment: the only difference was in the plist file. i decided to simply change the plist information- as it was a change only in one property. so i got it to work.            i would still like it if someone knows if it is possible to have 2 separate -cal targets and run them interchangeably, so an answer that tells me how i can do that, or one that tells me that we can only have one -cal target in one iOS project will both be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i have learnt, both from alannichols and from github, calabash framework starts a server when you run the app on xcode, so having multiple xchemas was a bust. we have gone back to simply swapping out the plist file in the -cal schema when we need to.

so to sum up- it is impossible to have multiple schemas and run from the command line on demand.